# Optimization Problem - Similar to Quadratic

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization, quadratic-programming

I’m quite new to the forum and to optimisation, so my apologies if the question is trivial or in the wrong section. I've rewittren the question to clarify my doubt (I was previously writing from an iPad and now I'm using my laptop, I hope it helps).

The problem I'm trying to solve is to estimate the matrices $A$ and $B$ of a linear system

$$
x(k+1) = A x(k) + B u(k)
$$
using a moving horizon estimation (MHE) approach. The MHE formulation is given by
$$
\begin{align}
\min_{\hat{A},\hat{B}} \quad & \sum_{i=k-N+1}^{k} (x_i - x_{i\mid k})^T Q (x_i - x_{i\mid k}) \\
s.t. \quad & x_{i+1 \mid k} = \hat{A} x_i + \hat{B} u_i \\
& (\hat{A},\hat{B}) \in \mathcal{M}
\end{align}
$$

where $x_i \in \mathbb{R}^n$ and $u_i \in \mathbb{R}^p$ are measured states and inputs, $\hat{A} \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$ and $\hat{B} \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times p}$ are the estimated dynamics, $x_{i \mid k} \in \mathbb{R}^n$ is the estimate of $x_i$ made at time $k$, $N$ is the estimation horizon, $k$ is the current time instant, $Q$ is a positive definite matrix, and $\mathcal{M}$ defines upper and lower bounds on each element of $\hat{A}$ and $\hat{B}$.

Replacing the dynamic equation constraint into the objective, this problem can be rewritten as
$$
\begin{align}
\min_{\hat{A},\hat{B}} \quad & \begin{bmatrix}
(x_{k-N+1} - \hat{A} x_{k-N} + \hat{B} u_{k-N}) \\ \vdots \\ (x_{k} - \hat{A} x_{k-1} + \hat{B} u_{k-1})
\end{bmatrix}^T
\begin{bmatrix}
Q & & 0 \\
& \ddots & \\ 
0 & & Q
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
(x_{k-N+1} - \hat{A} x_{k-N} + \hat{B} u_{k-N}) \\ \vdots \\ (x_{k} - \hat{A} x_{k-1} + \hat{B} u_{k-1})
\end{bmatrix} \\
s.t. \quad & (\hat{A},\hat{B}) \in \mathcal{M}
\end{align}
$$

I've been trying to play around with this formulation to test different manners to achieve a traditionnal quadratic programming objective (i.e. $\frac{1}{2} X^T H X + f^T X + M$) in which my variable is the estimate of the matrices. My objective is to able to use this formulation to verify whether my past measurement data allows for the unique identification of the system (i.e., the resulting optimisation problem has a unique solution). The approach that I'm using rewrites the dynamics as

$$
x^T_{k+1 \mid k} = \begin{bmatrix} 
x^T_{k} & u^T_{k}
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
\hat{A}^T \\ \hat{B}^T
\end{bmatrix}
$$

which allows to rewrite the optimisation as

$$
\begin{align}
\min_{\theta}. \quad & F^T \theta^T \tilde{Q} \theta F - 2YQ \theta F +Y^T Q Y \quad \\
s.t. \quad & \theta \in M
\end{align}
$$

where

$$
\theta = \begin{bmatrix}
\hat{A}^T \\ \hat{B}^T
\end{bmatrix} \\
F = \begin{bmatrix}
x_{k-N} & u_{k-N} \\ \vdots & \vdots \\ x_{k-1} & u_{k-1}
\end{bmatrix} \\ 
Y = \begin{bmatrix}
x_{k-N+1} \\ \vdots \\ x_{k}
\end{bmatrix} \\
\tilde{Q} = \begin{bmatrix}
Q & & 0 \\
& \ddots & \\ 
0 & & Q
\end{bmatrix}
$$

$\theta$ is a $(n+p) \times n$ matrix, $\tilde{Q}$ is positive definite and $F$ is a $N \times (n+p)$ matrix, with $N \geq n+p$.

The structure resembles a conventional quadratic optimisation. My problem is that the variable I’m trying to optimise is multiplied by a (known) matrix on the outside, and therefore the problem cannot be directly solved using a quadratic solver. I tried to google this problem, as I imagine it is probably not uncommon and can be dealt with in a simple way, but I couldn’t find anything (I imagine I was not searching for the correct terms).

Is there a way to convert this problem into a traditional quadratic optimisation?

Comment: Is $\theta$ a vector or matrix?

Comment: Are the constraints $\theta \in M$ linear?

Comment: Hi @BrianBorchers, I edited the question to reply to your questions. $\theta$ is a vector and M are just bounds on the elements of $\theta$.

Comment: Is $Q$ positive semi definite?

Comment: Add the variable $x$ and the constraint $x=\Theta F$, then it becomes a standard linearly constrained QP (assuming $Q \ge 0$).

Comment: Hi @copper.hat, I edited the question to mention that $Q$ is positive definite and some context that might be helpful. Using the method you proposed, I would still need some condition on F to guarantee uniqueness of solution?

Comment: Hi: is that the minimization of a cost function ? If so, check out the llinear quadratic gaussian (LQG ) stochastic optimal control problem because it looks pretty similar to that. There might be something in the LQG literature that points you in the correct direction.

Comment: A priori there is no reason to expect uniqueness. It is not clear to me what $F$ is.

Comment: @copper.hat sorry for the back and forth with extra information. I've tried to rewrite the question with as much detail as I can. My expectation of uniquess comes from the fact that I'm trying to estimate the dynamics of the system that is generating my data. I'm trying to understand whether I can establish conditions on the data that guarantee this uniqueness (analogously to the concept of persistence of excitation).

Comment: I have not looked closely, but I would imagine that you at least need complete controllability of the observed system.